# modifying code to get a different answer

Tags: java, methods

Here is my current code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;//importing scanner 

public class QuestionOne {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numberofDays;//these two lines define variables
    int sharePoints;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);//activating scanner
System.out.print("Number of days in the period: ");//asking question

numberofDays = keyboard.nextInt();//obtaining input by defining a variable as a keyboard input

System.out.print("Share points on the first day: ");//asking another question
sharePoints = keyboard.nextInt();//obtaining input by defining a variable as a keyboard input

numberofDays = validator(numberofDays,keyboard); // Validates Keyboard input

//above two lines print day and share points, as well as the first line of text (as it does not change)
outPutTablePrinter(numberofDays,sharePoints);

}

private static void outPutTablePrinter(int numberOfDays,int sharePoints){
    System.out.println("Day " + " Share Points");
    System.out.println(1 + "    " + sharePoints);
    for (int i = 2; i <= numberOfDays; i++) {
        if (numberOfDays % 2 == 0)
            if (i <= numberOfDays / 2) {
                sharePoints = sharePoints + 50;
                System.out.println(i + "    " + sharePoints);
            } else {
                sharePoints = sharePoints - 25;
                System.out.println(i + "    " + sharePoints);
            } else {
            if (i <= numberOfDays / 2 + 1) {
                sharePoints = sharePoints + 50;
                System.out.println(i + "    " + sharePoints);
            } else {
                sharePoints = sharePoints - 25;
                System.out.println(i + "    " + sharePoints);
                // above nested if else statements essentially calculate 
and concatenate the variables to obtain an answer that is then printed 
and repeated until the number of days is reached (starting from day two)
            }
        }
    }
}

private static int validator(int numberOfDays,Scanner keyboard){
    while (numberOfDays < 10 || numberOfDays > 20)//while loop makes sure 
the conditions stay true
    {
        System.out.println("The number of days doesn’t meet the required 
criteria, enter it again");
        System.out.print("Number of days in the period: ");
        numberOfDays = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    return numberOfDays;
}
}
```

What the code currently does is ask for the days of the period and the initial price and then it displays the price for every day until the last one in the period. For example, if I put 11 days as my period and 550 as my initial stock value then I would get the following:

```
Day Share Points
1 550
2 600
3 575
4 625
5 600
6 650
7 625
8 675
9 650
10 700
11 675
```

What I instead want to do, is change it so the final answer (if the same values are entered), should look something like this:

```
The share points on the final day would be: 675
```

Comment: What is the problem you've encounter and how have you tried to solve it?

Comment: So you want to add text to the output string.  Have you tried going to the line of code which outputs that string and typing the text there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static void outPutTablePrinter(int numberOfDays,int sharePoints){
//        System.out.println("Day " + " Share Points");
//        System.out.println(1 + "    " + sharePoints);
        for (int i = 2; i <= numberOfDays; i++) {
            if (numberOfDays % 2 == 0)
                if (i <= numberOfDays / 2) {
                    sharePoints = sharePoints + 50;
//                    System.out.println(i + "    " + sharePoints);
                } else {
                    sharePoints = sharePoints - 25;
//                    System.out.println(i + "    " + sharePoints);
                } else {
                if (i <= numberOfDays / 2 + 1) {
                    sharePoints = sharePoints + 50;
//                    System.out.println(i + "    " + sharePoints);
                } else {
                    sharePoints = sharePoints - 25;
//                    System.out.println(i + "    " + sharePoints);
                    // above nested if else statements essentially calculate
                    // and concatenate the variables to obtain an answer that is then printed
                    // and repeated until the number of days is reached (starting from day two)
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The share points on the final day would be: "+sharePoints);
}
```

Here is the output

```
Number of days in the period: 11
Share points on the first day: 550
The share points on the final day would be: 675
```